# Dead keys not working in Emacs-Lisp mode *only*

Tags: input-method, emacs-lisp-mode

I've been having a really annoying bug when editing elisp files recently: dead keys do not work, but only when I am in Emacs-Lisp mode. If I type a key that is configured as a dead key (say, `'`), I get a prompt that says `Emacs-Lisp:` on my mini buffer. Then, typing any normal letter gives me the corresponding accented character (say, `á`), but hitting `SPC`, which *should* give me the single quote character `'`, does nothing instead. Deactivating Emacs-Lisp mode and going into fundamental mode solves the issue. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Just a disclaimer: some people (including myself) were affected a while ago by a [seemingly similar issue](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2009-05/msg00167.html) that required them to explicitly require `iso-transl` to get dead keys. I've already done this, and it did fix most of my problems with dead keys, but this weird issue in Emacs-Lisp mode appeared afterwards.

**Edit**:

If I don't require `iso-transl` (or do `emacs -q`) then the problem changes: I get undefined dead keys, just like I did before, but they don't bring up the `Emacs-Lisp:` prompt on my mini buffer. If I do e.g. `C-h k <dead-acute>`, then the `Emacs-Lisp:` prompt comes up and no help gets shown, *except* that if I try to type `<dead-acute>` several times and then hit `C-g` the following slightly different message pops up:

```
<dead-acute> C-g (translated from <dead-acute> <dead-acute> <dead-acute> C-g) is undefined
```

I'm running Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I *think* before I had it compiled from source and it was giving me the same problem, but I can't quite remember.

**Edit 2**

If I do `(describe-key [dead-acute])`, Emacs says that it is undefined. If I try [this trick](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/654/2504) to find where the key is bound, it still shows me the `Emacs-Lisp:` prompt as above, except that if I hit `C-g` right after I get

```
At Point: (nil nil nil nil)
Minor-mode: 
Local: 1
Global: 1
```

This is different from the message it prints for `C-g` on its own. If I try to do the same on a different mode, I need to press `SPC` after `<dead-acute>` to get an answer

```
At Point: (nil nil nil nil)
Minor-mode: 
Local: 
Global: self-insert-command
```

Comment: What does `C-h k dead_acute` show (i.e. type `C-h k` then a dead key)? Do you have the same problem in `emacs -q`? What Emacs version are you running, on what operating system?

Comment: @Gilles Just added more details above.

Comment: It would help to know what `dead-acute` is bound to. `C-h k` isn't helpful here because it's a prefix but [`M-: (describe-key [dead-acute]) RET`](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4203/why-does-c-c-c-x-look-like-an-empty-keymap/4207#4207) should give the right information. Even better, [find where `dead-acute` is bound](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-i-find-out-in-which-keymap-a-key-is-bound/654#654).

Comment: @Gilles just tried that, but the output didn't seem very informative, cf. edit above.

Comment: I have no explanation for why Emacs Lisp mode would zonk out like this, but I [posted an answer to the seemingly similar issue](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2568/problem-dead-acute-is-undefined-appearing-when-typing-greek-stress/5817#5817) that may help you (or not).

Comment: Updating to a more recent version of Emacs seems to solve the problem. 
In my case, I am using 24.5.1.